# Why won't my for loop work? (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

**Yes, this is homework. I'm just trying to understand why this doesn't seem to work.**

I'm trying to find the longest substring in a string that's in alphabetical order. I make a list of random letters, and say the length is 19. When I run my code, it prints out indices 0 through 17. (I know this happens because I subtract 1 from the range) However, when I leave off that -1, it tells me the "string index is out of range." Why does that happen?

```
s = 'cntniymrmbhfinjttbiuqhib'
sub = ''
longest = []

for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        sub += s[i]
        longest.append(sub)
    elif s[i-1] <= s[i]:
        sub += s[i]
        longest.append(sub)
        sub = ' '
    else:
        sub = ' '
print(longest)
print ('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + max(longest, key=len))
```

*I've also tried a few other methods*

If I just say:

```
for i in s:
```

it throws an error, saying "string indices must be integers, not str." This seems like a much simpler way to iterate through the string, but how would I compare individual letters this way?

This is Python 2.7 by the way.

Edit: I'm sure my if/elif statements could be improved but that's the first thing I could think of. I can come back to that later if need be.

Comment: try `for  i in enumerate(s):` Should work off the top of my head

Comment: "Why does that happen?" Hint: If `s[i]` is the last character in the string, then what is `s[i+1]`?

Comment: This is because `for i in s` will literally take the elements of `s` as an array, so the first element will be `c`, the second will be `n` etc. You want to find the index, so you want to get the number of the element you are at, and `enumerate` should do that. If it works I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't  `enumerate` return pairs (index, value)? Would be `for i, c in enumerate(s):`

Comment: it seems enumerate does return pairs. That then causes issues with the indices, since it is expecting an int, not a tuple. Can I still access a specific letter in the list using enumerate?

Comment: Don't use `else` in `for` iterators. `else` always returned some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm sure my if/elif statements could be improved but that's the first
>   thing I could think of. I can come back to that later if need be.

@or1426's solution creates a list of the currently longest sorted sequence and copies it over to `longest` whenever a longer sequence is found. This creates a new list every time a longer sequence is found, and appends to a list for every character. This is actually very fast in Python, but see below.

@Deej's solution keeps the currently longest sorted sequence in a string variable, and every time a longer substring is found (even if it's a continuation of the current sequence) the substring is saved to a list. The list ends up having *all* sorted substrings of the original string, and the longest is found by using a call to `max`.

Here is a faster solution that only keeps track of the indices of the currently largest sequence, and only makes changes to longest when it finds a character that is not in sorted order:

```
def bjorn4(s):
    # we start out with s[0] being the longest sorted substring (LSS)
    longest = (0, 1)    # the slice-indices of the longest sorted substring
    longlen = 1         # the length of longest
    cur_start = 0       # the slice-indices of the *current* LSS
    cur_stop = 1

    for ch in s[1:]:       # skip the first ch since we handled it above
        end = cur_stop-1   # cur_stop is a slice index, subtract one to get the last ch in the LSS
        if ch >= s[end]:   # if ch >= then we're still in sorted order..
            cur_stop += 1  # just extend the current LSS by one
        else:
            # we found a ch that is not in sorted order
            if longlen < (cur_stop-cur_start):
                # if the current LSS is longer than longest, then..
                longest = (cur_start, cur_stop)    # store current in longest
                longlen = longest[1] - longest[0]  # precompute longlen

            # since we can't add ch to the current LSS we must create a new current around ch
            cur_start, cur_stop = cur_stop, cur_stop+1

    # if the LSS is at the end, then we'll not enter the else part above, so
    # check for it after the for loop
    if longlen < (cur_stop - cur_start):
        longest = (cur_start, cur_stop)

    return s[longest[0]:longest[1]]
```

How much faster?  It's almost twice as fast as orl1426 and three times faster than deej. As always that depends on your input. The more chunks of sorted substrings that exist, the faster the above algorithm will be compared to the others. E.g. on an input string of length 100000 containing alternating 100 random chars and 100 in-order chars, I get:

```
bjorn4: 2.4350001812
or1426: 3.84699988365
deej  : 7.13800001144
```

if I change it to alternating 1000 random chars and 1000 sorted chars, then I get:

```
bjorn4: 23.129999876
or1426: 38.8380000591
deej  : MemoryError
```

**Update:**
Here is a further optimized version of my algorithm, with the comparison code:

```
import random, string
from itertools import izip_longest
import timeit

def _randstr(n):
    ls = []
    for i in range(n):
        ls.append(random.choice(string.lowercase))
    return ''.join(ls)

def _sortstr(n):
    return ''.join(sorted(_randstr(n)))

def badstr(nish):
    res = ""
    for i in range(nish):
        res += _sortstr(i)
        if len(res) >= nish:
            break
    return res

def achampion(s):
    start = end = longest = 0
    best = ""
    for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s, s[1:]):
        end += 1
        if c2 and c1 <= c2:
            continue
        if (end-start) > longest:
            longest = end - start
            best = s[start:end]
        start = end
    return best

def bjorn(s):
    cur_start = 0
    cur_stop = 1
    long_start = cur_start
    long_end = cur_stop

    for ch in s[1:]:      
        if ch < s[cur_stop-1]:
            if (long_end-long_start) < (cur_stop-cur_start):
                long_start = cur_start
                long_end = cur_stop
            cur_start = cur_stop
        cur_stop += 1

    if (long_end-long_start) < (cur_stop-cur_start):
        return s[cur_start:cur_stop]
    return s[long_start:long_end]


def or1426(s):
    longest = [s[0]]
    current = [s[0]]
    for char in s[1:]:
        if char >= current[-1]: # current[-1] == current[len(current)-1]
            current.append(char)
        else:            
            current=[char]
        if len(longest) < len(current):
            longest = current
    return ''.join(longest)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'achampion:', round(min(timeit.Timer(
        "achampion(rstr)",
        setup="gc.enable();from __main__ import achampion, badstr; rstr=badstr(30000)"
    ).repeat(15, 50)), 3)

    print 'bjorn:', round(min(timeit.Timer(
        "bjorn(rstr)",
        setup="gc.enable();from __main__ import bjorn, badstr; rstr=badstr(30000)"
    ).repeat(15, 50)), 3)

    print 'or1426:', round(min(timeit.Timer(
        "or1426(rstr)",
        setup="gc.enable();from __main__ import or1426, badstr; rstr=badstr(30000)"
    ).repeat(15, 50)), 3)
```

With output:

```
achampion: 0.274
bjorn: 0.253
or1426: 0.486
```

changing the data to be random:

```
achampion: 0.350
bjorn: 0.337
or1426: 0.565
```

and sorted:

```
achampion: 0.262
bjorn: 0.245
or1426: 0.503
```

"no, no, it's not dead, it's resting"

Comment: thanks! I know my answer was very crude, and it's cool to see the different ways other people go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the line `if s[i] <= s[i+1]:`. If `i=18` (the final iteration of your loop without the `-1` in it). Then `i+1=19` is out of bounds.

Note that the line `elif s[i-1] <= s[i]:` is also probably not doing what you want it to. When `i=0` we have `i-1 = -1`. Python allows negative indices to mean counting from the back of the indexed object so `s[-1]` is the *last* character in the list (s[-2] would be the second last etc.).

A simpler way to get the previous and next character is to use `zip` whilst slicing the string to count from the first and second characters respectively.

`zip` works like this if you haven't seen it before:

```
>>> for char, x in zip(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3,4]):
>>>    print char, x
'a' 1
'b' 2
'c' 3
```

So you can just do:

```
for previous_char, char, next_char in zip(string, string[1:], string[2:]):
```

To iterate over all the triples of characters without messing up at the ends.

However there is a much simpler way to do this. Instead of comparing the current character in the string to other characters in the string you should compare it with the last character in the current string of alphabetised characters for example:

```
s = "abcdabcdefa"
longest = [s[0]]
current = [s[0]]
for char in s[1:]:
    if char >= current[-1]: # current[-1] == current[len(current)-1]
        current.append(char)
    else:            
        current=[char]
    if len(longest) < len(current):
        longest = current
print longest
```

This avoids having to do any fancy indexing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the elif statement wasn't quite doing what I wanted... I'll have to figure out another way to do that then. As for the i+1 being out of bounds, that makes sense but I hoped it would cycle through everything and then once it got to that point it would stop. Apparently that's not how it works though.

Comment: @Deej zipping several slices of the list together stops exactly how you want it to. Note that in the example I gave the first list only has three elements and the second has four and it stopped after three.

Comment: That seems to be cutting off the first and last letter in my list. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Deej This is because the first element doesn't have a previous element and the last element doesn't have a next element. This is how you get the "cycle through everything and then once it got to that point it would stop" behaviour you wanted.

There is a much neater solution though which I've edited my answer to include.

Comment: thanks for your help. The above solution didn't quite get what I'm looking for, but it did help me learn more about what I can do with lists and everything. I finally figured out how to get what I needed (though not pretty at all, it does what I need)

Answer (score 1):

Now Deej has an answer I feel more comfortable posting answers to homework.
Just reordering @Deej's logic a little you can simplify to:

```
sub = ''
longest = []
for i in range(len(s)-1):  # -1 simplifies the if condition
    sub += s[i]
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        continue           # Keep adding to sub until condition fails
    longest.append(sub)    # Only add to longest when condition fails
    sub = ''

max(longest, key=len)
```

But as mentioned by @thebjorn this has the issue of keeping every ascending partition in a list (in memory). You could fix this by using a generator, and I only put the rest here for instructional purposes:

```
def alpha_partition(s):
    sub = ''
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        sub += s[i]
        if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
            continue
        yield sub
        sub = ''

max(alpha_partition(s), key=len)
```

This certainly wont be the fastest solution (string construction and indexing) but it's quite simple to change, use zip to avoid the indexing into the string and indexes to avoid string construction and addition:

```
from itertools import izip_longest   # For py3.X use zip_longest
def alpha_partition(s):
    start = end = 0
    for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s, s[1:]):
        end += 1
        if c2 and c1 <= c2:
            continue
        yield s[start:end]
        start = end

max(alpha_partition(s), key=len)
```

Which should operate pretty efficiently and be only slightly slower than the iterative indexing approach from @thebjorn due to the generator overhead.

Using s*100
`alpha_partition()`: 1000 loops, best of 3: 448 µs per loop
@thebjorn: 1000 loops, best of 3: 389 µs per loop

For reference turning the generator into an iterative function:

```
from itertools import izip_longest   # For py3.X use zip_longest
def best_alpha_partition(s):
    start = end = longest = 0
    best = ""
    for c1, c2 in izip_longest(s, s[1:]):
        end += 1
        if c2 and c1 <= c2:
            continue
        if (end-start) > longest:
            longest = end - start
            best = s[start:end]
        start = end
    return best
best_alpha_partition(s)
```

`best_alpha_partition()`: 1000 loops, best of 3: 306 µs per loop

I personally prefer the generator form because you would use exactly the same generator for finding the minimum, the top 5, etc. very reusable vs. the iterative function which only does one thing.

Comment: looks interesting, however, I don't think your algorithm is correct.. e.g. on inputs `a`, `ab`, `aabc`, `babc`, `cbabc`, yours is getting different results than the others (I only tested `best_alpha_partition`..

Comment: thanks, fixed - it didn't handle the last partition.

Comment: Nicely done!  You can change it to use indexes by changing the assignment to best to `best = (start, end)`, but I had to work really hard to show any difference in from timeit (basically, long strings where the sorted substrings were in order from shortest to longest -- and turning on gc).

Comment: Yes, I found tuple creation was no better and normally slightly slower than straight slicing, so left it that way.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so after reading your responses and trying all kinds of different things, I finally came up with a solution that gets exactly what I need. It's not the prettiest code, but it works. I'm sure the solutions mentioned would work as well, however I couldn't figure them out. Here's what I did:

```
s = 'inaciaebganawfiaefc'
sub = ''
longest = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if (i+1) < len(s) and s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        sub += s[i]
        longest.append(sub)
    elif i >= 0 and s[i-1] <= s[i]:
        sub += s[i]
        longest.append(sub)
        sub = ''
    else:
        sub = ''
print ('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + max(longest, key=len))
```

Comment: A simple improvement is not to append in your `if` condition, you only need to add the substring in the `elif` condition. I also believe the final else is unnecessary.